# How to add multiple audio files at specific times, on a silence audio file using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to overlay audio files at specific times, on an existing silence.mp3. Something like that:

```
[----[...audio1...]----------[...audio2...]---------------]
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -y -i silence.mp3 -itsoffset 4 -i audio1.mp3 -itsoffset 30 -i audio2.mp3 -c:a copy final.mp3
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: Probably an obvious answer, but is `silence.mp3` actually silent?

Comment: @llogan, yes silence.mp3 is silent, and as a duration of 60 seconds when played in VLC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several methods.

## adelay, amix

Use the [adelay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=4s:all=1[0a];[1]adelay=30s:all=1[1a];[0a][1a]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
```

Note that the amix filter will reduce volume of the output to prevent clipping. Followup with dynaudnorm or volume filters if desired.

## adelay, concat filter

Or adelay and [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filters. This assumes `audio1.mp4` is 10 seconds long, and both inputs have the same sample rate and channel layout:

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0]adelay=4s:all=1[0a];[1]adelay=16s:all=1[1a];[0a][1a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[a]" -map "[a]" output.mp3
```

## anullsrc, concat demuxer

Or generate silent files as spacers with the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 4 4.mp3
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 16 16.mp3
```

Create input.txt:

```
file '4.mp3'
file 'audio1.mp3'
file '16.mp3'
file 'audio2.mp3'
```

Then use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp3
```

Comment: So the filter-complex for 3 files would be like this: `"[0]adelay=4s:all=1[0a];[1]adelay=30s:all=1[1a];[2]adelay=50s:all=1[2a];[0a][1a][2a]amix=inputs=3[a]"` ?

Comment: @boblapointe Yes, looks correct. I forgot to mention to make sure you're using a recent ffmpeg. The old versions don't support `s` so you have to provide a value in milliseconds, and they don't support `all=1`, so you have to manually provide a delay for each channel. For example, stereo with 4 second delay: `adelay=4000|4000`.

Comment: shouldn't the input.txt file be `file '4.mp3'
file 'audio1.mp3'
file '16.mp3'
file 'audio2.mp3'` ?

Comment: do you offer freelance services ? how can I reach you ?

Comment: @boblapointe Not anymore, but [Gyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5726027/gyan) does.